# Axes tick labelling in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following plot of data:

[image: plot]

I would like to have month labels on the x-axis i.e. Jan, Feb, ..., Dec equally spaced. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify `XtickLabel` property for this purpose:

```
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', {'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', ...
   'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'})
```

If not all ticks are showing, you can tinker with the `XTick` property as well:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', linspace(1, N, 12))
```

where `N` is the total number of samples plotted.

Read [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-axis-parameters.html#f6-29060) for more information.